# Why I can't add .NET DLLs at run time

Tags: c#, codedom

Using CodeDOM I have something like this:

```
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Linq.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.Linq.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
```

and when I run a program, this is the the error I get for the last three DLLs, the first two (System.DLL and System.Windows.Forms.DLL ) have no problem and error but as soon as I add those last three lines to load those DLLs too, then I get errors like the one in the picture.
So weird and annoying and couldn't find a way to fix it.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that your compiler setup is looking at .NET 3.0 or older (linq was added in 3.5).  Off the top of my head, I don't know how to change it (perhaps you can add the fully qualified assembly name with version number?)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair : I have set the target platform to 4.0 in Visual Studio.  It isn't just Linq, even for the last one that is System.Core it is giving a similar error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh Wow! it was tricky!

It doesn't care what is the Target Platform that Visual Studio is set on, what it looks at is its own **CodeProvider** class. Previously I was using its [default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx).  But it also has another constructor that takes a Dictionary parameter. In this parameter we are specifying what version of .NET should be used. So instead of just creating a new CodeProvider object I should do it like this:

```
    Dictionary<string, string> compilerInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    compilerInfo.Add("CompilerVersion", "v3.5");
    CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider(compilerInfo);
```

Now it works.