# Metadata for System.Core.DLL couldn't be found in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, codedom

I want to compile code using CodeDom and to initializse the compiler paramees I am doing something likd this:

```
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll"); //only works in .NET 4.0
```

IF I put the target framework of Visual Studio on .NET 4.0, no problem, it works. BUT if I put the target framework of Visual Studio on .NET 3.5, then it gives me the error in picture. And actually I need to run it unnder .NET 3.5 :(

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I can't add .NET DLLs at run time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887454/why-i-cant-add-net-dlls-at-run-time)